# Allow user to change homepage

Tags: plugin-development, homepage

What I was trying to do is to let my visitors choose their homepage (each for 1 of 7 locations) on my site, and remember their choice until they choose different location. Does anyone know some sufficient way to do that?

Comment: why don't they bookmark it?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. What I meant was to let them choose a main page. When they enter my website, they can choose 1 of 7 different locations and depending what they click, this page will become start page until they change it.

Comment: I actually understood it, so still if they want to get to your site on page Z why don't they just bookmark it? IIRC there is some JS API that can help, but in general, how else can you manage such a thing without forcing the users to login first, which I assume you don't want to go that way.

Comment: Just place a cookie that remembers the users choice.